# ReferenceError: Discord client is not defined

Tags: javascript, discord.js

This is my code :

```
const Discord = require("discord.js");
const client = new Discord.Client();

client.login("<Discord Token Here>");

console.log("start");

client.on('message', (message) => {
  if (message.content == "бот") {
    message.channel.send("моя_статья");
  }
});
```

My problem is on this line -

```
client.login("<Discord Token Here>");
```

> ReferenceError: client is not defined

please can you help me with this.

Comment: At a guess, the Discord client library isn't loading. Or it may be  that it's asynchronous, so you need to wait till it's loaded?

Comment: I've flagged for moderator attention to have the tokens redacted, but I ***HIGHLY*** recommend you change those tokens right now before they get abused.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you follow all steps [Discord.js](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/general/welcome)

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const client = new Discord.Client();

client.on('ready', () => {
  console.log(`Logged in as ${client.user.tag}!`);
  console.log("start");
});

client.on('message', message => {
  if (message.content == "бот") {
    message.channel.send("моя_статья");
  }
});

client.login('<Discord Token Here>');
```